# EditText Value in a dialog

Tags: java, android

I dont understand, the dialog and everything works but as soon as I get the value from the EditText and assign it to val, run the app it crashes within the onClick on success.

I get an error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

```
public void createDialogBox() {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();

    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    //


    builder.setView(R.layout.custom_dialog)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // On success

                    EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.shopping_list_recycler_view);
                    String val = text.getText().toString();

                    adapter = new ShoppingListViewAdapter(test, MainShoppingListViewActivity.this);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                    adapter.addTest(new Data(val, "Created by: Me"));
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // On failure
                    Toast.makeText(MainShoppingListViewActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
            // Desired icon for the dialog box
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .show();
}
```

Logs

```
06-03 22:37:29.778 21364-21364/familyshopshare.com.familyshopshare E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: familyshopshare.com.familyshopshare, PID: 21364
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
 at familyshopshare.com.familyshopshare.MainShoppingListViewActivity$3.onClick(MainShoppingListViewActivity.java:93)
 at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:157)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Please add the crash logs.

Comment: That's the full log from the error. I have tried to clean and rebuild the project. I don't seem to understand why it doesn't work. I have done this plenty of times before, a bit random if you ask me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the view of the dialog from the `LayoutInflater` like this:

```
View rootView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
```

Then you can call

```
EditText text = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.shopping_list_recycler_view);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the views inside the Dialog,then you have to inflate the layout like this -

```
  View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
```

Then initialize your views -

```
final EditText text = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.shopping_list_recycler_view);
```

and set it as view in the dialog-

```
builder.setView(rootView);
```

Then you can access your EditText inside onClick() like this -

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
         // On success 
         String val = text.getText().toString();

}
```

From the crash , it is clear you are incorrectly typecasting view ids.
You are typecasting `shopping_list_recycler_view` as an EditText  which is not correct. Please check your your xml and use proper view id.

Comment: `(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.shopping_list_recycler_view);` looks suspicious, no? Read the error again

Comment: Yes R.id.shopping_list_recycler_view is not correct, it was suppose to be ShoppinglistName must of added that by accident I have just corrected it. This wasnt the problem. However, your solution has resolved it. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check your XML for the correct ID that is your `EditText`.

Your error is very clear.

```
RecyclerView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
```

You also are searching in the Activity with the `findViewById` like you have, so you'll need to get it from the dialog's view.

```
// Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
// Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
//
View dialogView = getLayoutInflate().inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);

// Get your Views
final EditText editText = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.someEditText); 

// Build and show the dialog
builder.setView(dialogView)
       ...
       .create().show();
```

Comment: The ID was a typo, android auto selected it, it has been resolved with the correct ID. Thank you for pointing it out :). 

I see what you have done, and understand it. Thank you again :)